404 when using Typescript project reference
I have a Typescript project referencing another Typescript project. It is for use in a browser. The project builds fine, but when I run it (via liveserver), I get a 404 when the trying to load the dependency. I can see why, the dependency was never copied to the output directory and the path to the file got truncated.
<repo root>
|-- Common
|   |-- TypescriptUtilities
|       |-- util.ts
|       |-- tsconfig.json
|-- Experimental
    |-- Typescript
        |-- index.html
        |-- index.ts
        |-- tsconfig.json

// index.ts
import { Util } from "../../Common/TypescriptUtilities/util.js";
let array: number[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Util.shuffle(array);

// Experimental/Typescript/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../Common/TypescriptUtilities",
    }
  ]
}

// Common/TypescriptUtilities/tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "composite": true,
    },
    "references": []
}

The error I get is GET http://127.0.0.1:5503/Common/TypescriptCommon/util.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).
As you can see ../../ is missing from the path. Even if it was there, I expect that would create problems in production. It seems better to have everything copied to the output directory.
Is there a way to configure this? Or is there a better solution?
Background: I am new to Typescript and web development in general. I am confused about the module and moduleResolution options as they often seem to refer to node.js which I am not using(?!). However, I could not get the project to compile without "moduleResolution": "node".
